# Force computation on pistons connected by water

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, pressure

I like to make things but I don't know any math and am having trouble with calculating the force in the system shown below. In this illustration we see a set of $2$ pistons connected with a hose of incomprehensible water. To keep the math simple the first piston has an effective area of $2^2$ inches, and the second piston of $1^2$ inch. If the larger piston is pressurized with $100$ PSI, how many pounds of force will be applied on the second piston?[image]

Comment: Title should be rather descriptive of the actual question

Comment: Is the area of the large piston 2 square inches? Or is it 2 inches squared, i.e., 4 square inches?

Answer (score 1):

If the system is in equilibrium, the pressures on both pistons are the same 100 psi.  This is because pressure is transmitted uniformly throughout the fluid.  As a result, the force on the 1" square piston is 100 lb, but the force on the 2" square piston is 200 lb.  This type of arrangement is the principle behind the operation of a hydraulic jack.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure is same in both pistons however you get twice the force for larger one.

This is pascals law refer wikipedia 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law

This is used in hydraulic lifting as written by @Chet_Miller

As to calculate the magnitude just equate pressure(F/A)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This part should help.          " If a U-tube is filled with water and pistons are placed at each end, pressure exerted against the left piston will be transmitted throughout the liquid and against the bottom of the right piston. (The pistons are simply "plugs" that can slide freely but snugly inside the tube.) The pressure that the left piston exerts against the water will be exactly equal to the pressure the water exerts against the right piston. "  (from wikipedia)

Answer (score -1):

Considering :

- the whole system horizontal in order to ignore the effect of gravity over pressures.
- both pistons are steady.

The forces applied on both sides of one piston (by the air and the water) are equal but opposite because piston is not moving. That means pressure on both sides of one piston are the same too (because F=P*S where P is the pressure, F the force and S the section).

It means the bottom air pressure is the same as the water one, water pressure is homogeneous because in steady state and gravity is ingnored and thus pressure is still the same on the top air volume. All the pressures are 100 Psi.

So let's call P the pressure of the top air volume  and S the 1 square inches section of the bottom piston. The force you are looking for is F = 100 Psi * 1square inch = 100 lbf. But keep in mind that the sum of forces applied to the pistons are null with my assumptions.